# Windows Phone get height and width of grid

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I try to get get height and width of grid:

```
int numberOfColumnsInGameView = (int)(gameView.Width / objectSize);
int numberOfRowsInGameView = (int)(gameView.Height / objectSize -0.5);
```

Where `gameView` is grid. When I try assign to variable I have that var = `NaN`

Comment: is `objectSize` set to 0 perhaps? Actually, given that you're assigning this to int, I can't see how you got NaN from it. More details, please.

Comment: No, no, no objectSize is const and equal 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Grid.ActualHeight` and `Grid.ActualWidth` properties.
You should use `Height` and `Width` only if you need to set a new value.

Answer (score 0):

The most conservative way is probably to do something like this:

```
private double HeightOf(FrameworkElement element)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(element.Height))
        return element.ActualHeight;
    if (double.IsNaN(element.ActualHeight))
        return element.Height;
    return Math.Max(element.Height, element.ActualHeight);
}
```

This way, you cover the following cases:

- Element is rendered, but no explicit height is set (→ `ActualHeight`)
- Element is not rendered yet, but has an explicit height (→ `Height`)
- Neither one (will return 0)

Answer (score 0):

Thx I understood.

```
this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded; 
.........
private void GeneranteLevel(int level)
    {
int numberOfColumnsInGameView = (int)(gameView.ActualWidth / objectSize);
int numberOfRowsInGameView = (int)(gameView.ActualHeight / objectSize -0.5);
........
```